# What is the meaning of similar JA3 in many APK malware analysis reports?

Tags: malware

In an online malware analysis website called - "Joe Sandbox", I found a few reports of APKS that have the exact same [JA3 fingerprint](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3):

https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/103507/0/html
https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/208046/0/html
https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/209043/0/html
https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/209453/0/html

Since they all share the same JA fingerprint, does it mean there is any connection between them? (By "connection" I mean - If they all were created by the same the developer, if they all were targeted a specific person etc) if not, why do they share the same JA3 fingerprint value?

Comment: Do you know what a JA3 fingerprint is and how it is made?

Answer (score 1):

JA3 is a fingerprint of the TLS stack of the TLS client and its specific configuration based on the ClientHello. As can be seen from [this list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/salesforce/ja3/master/lists/osx-nix-ja3.csv) the same JA3 fingerprint does not necessarily mean the same software or author. It might be for example possible that multiple authors use a specific TLS stack in the default configuration. But, a specific JA3 might nevertheless be used as a possible indicator of compromise, especially if this fingerprint is different from other (known good) programs in the same network.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to understand what is a JA3 signatures from the authors (https://github.com/salesforce/ja3), but looks that is a false positive on the Joe Sandbox.

Comment: Why is it a false positive? If all those APKs use the same network library, the JA3 fingerprint would be the same.